# How to write scenario to verlify a list of values displayed?

Tags: gherkin

How to write a gherkin scenario in which the user clicks on a menu button and he should see a list of sub-menus displayed.I tried:

```
Scenario Outline:Display of the login page
Given User is an admin
When user clicks on the menu
Then he should see the <list> displayed
Examples:
|  list                                            |
|  loginform, UsernameField, PasswordField         |
```

Answer (score 0):

Your description of the scenario and the scenario itself contradict each other. You write about sub-menus, the scenario lists fields. As the very first step, discuss the scenarios with your colleagues. When you have a clear plan, you can take on the syntax.
Syntax: why would you use a Scenario Outline when you only have a single example?

Comment: Actually, my question is how to write a scenario to chk the list of names displayed.?
Given iam on the landing page
when i click on XYZ button
Then the following SUBMENU1 should be displayed
        SUBMENU1          |
| Camera         |
| Collections   |
| record |
| Act      |